# Is it possible to use a Connected App in Customer Community?

Tags: customer-community, single-sign-on, connected-apps

I have researched Salesforce documentation and found out that it is possible to [enable Salesforce as an identity provider](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=identity_provider_enable.htm&type=5).
 Then you can [create a Connected App](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_overview_create_salesforce_connected_app.htm&type=5), and do the proper configuration in order to enable Single Sign On (SSO) for the Connected App.
 I would like to know if SSO will work from within the Customer Community for a user that has only a "Customer Community" profile.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is, here there is a video showing how to configure Salesforce as an IdP with a Connected App on Communities:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CGFvymniDZQ&t=0s